# RowMapper returns the list , but execute returned values returns the list size as 1?

Tags: spring, stored-procedures

1. please find below my sample code.The Row mapper returns a list. When printed it give me the size in the DB but when i check

> (List) employeeDaomap .get("allEmployees") i get the list size as 1 , and entire rows as one item? why what is the wrong in implementation

Also Spring doc says not to use rs.next(), how do we get the list of
    values from the DB

```
public class MyTestDAO extends StoredProcedure {

/** The log. */
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyTestDAO.class);
private static final String SPROC_NAME = "TestSchema.PKG_Test.prc_get_employee_list";
TestRowMapper mapper=new TestRowMapper();

public MyTestDAO(DataSource dataSource){
    super(dataSource, SPROC_NAME);
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("allEmployees", OracleTypes.CURSOR, mapper));
    compile();
}

/**
 * Gets the myemplist data from the DB
 * 
 */
public  List<EmployeeDAO> getEmployeeList()
        throws Exception {

    Map<String,Object> employeeDaomap =new HashMap<String,Object>(); 
    employeeDaomap =execute();
    log.info("employeeDaomap after execute ="+employeeDaomap);
    log.info("employeeDaomap after execute size ="+employeeDaomap.size()); // expected 1
    List<EmployeeDAO> list = (List<EmployeeDAO>) employeeDaomap .get("allEmployees");
    log.info("size of the list ="+list.size()); // need to get the size of the list ,
    return list;
}


private Map<String, Object> execute() {
    return super.execute(new HashMap<String, Object>());
}
}

public class TestRowMapper implements RowMapper<List<EmployeeDAO>> {
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestRowMapper.class);

@Override
public List<EmployeeDAO> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
        throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    rs.setFetchSize(3000);
    List<EmployeeDAO> responseItems = new ArrayList<EmployeeDAO>();
    EmployeeDAO responseItem = null;
    log.info("row num "+rowNum);
    while (rs.next()) {

        responseItem = new EmployeeDAO();
        responseItem.setID(rs.getString("id"));
        responseItem.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        responseItem.setDesc(rs.getString("desc"));
        responseItems.add(responseItem);

    }
    log.info("TestRowMapper items ="+responseItems);
    return responseItems;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the implements ResultSetExtractor  instead of RowMapper and provide implementation for extractData.

```
 




   public class TestRowMapper implements ResultSetExtractor<List<EmployeeDAO>> {
        static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestRowMapper.class);

    @Override
    public List<EMAccountResponse> extractData(ResultSet rs)
   throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
     rs.setFetchSize(3000);
        List<EmployeeDAO> responseItems = new ArrayList<EmployeeDAO>();
        EmployeeDAO responseItem = null;
        log.info("row num "+rowNum);
        while (rs.next()) {

            responseItem = new EmployeeDAO();
            responseItem.setID(rs.getString("id"));
            responseItem.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            responseItem.setDesc(rs.getString("desc"));
            responseItems.add(responseItem);

         }
        log.info("TestRowMapper items ="+responseItems);
        return responseItems;
  }
}
```